# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{-5}})$ normal over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I am to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{-5}})$ is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$ and find its Galois group.

How can it be normal? The [minimum polynomial is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=root(2%2Broot(-5))) $x^4-4x^2+9$ which has 2 distinct sets of roots: $\pm\sqrt{2+\sqrt{-5}}$ and $\pm\sqrt{2-\sqrt{-5}}$. Thus my field extension doesn't contain all the roots (its missing the latter two) and hence isn't normal. What am I missing? And how would I find the Galois group?

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2-\sqrt{-5}}} =\frac{\sqrt {2+\sqrt{-5}}}{3} $

Comment: You can actually denest that; Wolfram Alpha says that $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{-5}}$ equals $\frac{\sqrt{10}}2+i\frac{\sqrt2}2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note:$$\begin{cases}
\alpha=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{-5}}\\
\beta=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{-5}}
\end{cases}$$

The comment from [Matho123](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/154802/mathmo123) proves that $\alpha \beta=3$ and that the Galois group of $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is normal.

Regarding the Galois group $G$ of $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, what are its elements? You have the identity $\sigma_1$.

Consider $\sigma_2$ such that $\sigma_2(\alpha)=-\alpha$. Then $$3=\sigma_2(3)=\sigma_2(\alpha \beta)=\sigma_2(\alpha) \sigma_2(\beta)=-\alpha \sigma_2(\beta)$$ Hence $\sigma_2(\beta)=-\beta$ and the order of $\sigma_2$ is equal to $2$.

By similar considerations, one can prove that the elements $\sigma_3,\sigma_4$ of the Galois group $G$ such that $\sigma_3(\alpha)=\beta$, $\sigma_4(\alpha)=-\beta$ are also of order $2$.

Finally, the Galois group has four elements and all elements (except the identity) have order $2$. So $G$ is isomorphic to the [Klein four-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group).

Comment: If adjoining one root of your polynomial automatically gives you all the others, you’ve got a normal extension.